# How big is the Nether in Minecraft: XBox 360 Edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I know that the main world in Minecraft for XBox is limited to 1024 x 1024. I have heard that the Nether in this version has a permanent wall of bedrock around it, so it also has a fixed size. But how big is it?

Also, if the Nether is 1024x1024, how does the faster travel work? For example on PC, if you move 1 meter in the Nether, that's equivalent to 8 meters in the overworld. But given that the overworld is limited to 1024 across, what happens if you travel 1000 meters and then try to come back?

Comment: I haven't measured the Nether, but now that they've added coordinates to the map item, you can verify that the overworld is actually only 864 x 864, not a full 1024 x 1024.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this myself once I got to the Nether. In the Nether on Minecraft-XBox, maps do not show terrain, but they do report your position's coordinates. I went from one side of the Nether to the other (it is bounded by walls of bedrock). One one side, I was at coordinate Z = +140, On the other side, I was at coordinate Z = -140.

**The Nether is therefore approximately 280x280.**

This corresponds to the idea that the overworld is less than 1024x1024, since the Nether-to-Overworld distance multiplier is 1:3 in Minecraft-XBox, and 3 times 280 is 840.

If the Overworld is in fact 864x864, then the Nether is actually **288x288**. This would match my observation, as there are probably 2-4 layers of bedrock on each edge of the map, to ensure there are no gaps.

Answer (score 1):

On the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Nether#Portals_and_fast_travel), it states that the factor is 3 instead of 8. So that would make it 341 and 1/3 so it may be around that size. It also says in that page that world size is limited to 1024x1024 like you said and since the Nether is a world it might be that big too (although with my experience in the nether, i do not believe it is that big). All in all, its a 3:1 ratio.

Answer (score -3):

its the version thats why there's a wall it used to bve there on the Xbox 360 version so 1.16 never had a Wall Xbox 360 version did so the bedrock wall is made by the developer but was removed at 1.10 I think