# What happens when you reset the nether?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In Minecraft Xbox edition there is a setting that resets the nether. Does it just reset the nether? And does it affect the upper world?

Answer (score 5):

When you reset the nether world on the Xbox edition your seed gets reset, the map vanquished, your buildings forever **gone**.

More importantly, It also updates new and important things, for example a nether fortress with a blaze spawner. (now you can farm blaze rods!)

**Well, to all the those Minecraft PC gamers asking:** *What do you mean update new and important things?* Well here's your answer:

The Nether is approximately **280x280** on the Xbox version (not theoretically infinite like the PC version!). So you may not get a nether fortress in the whole map? What can you do? Reset the nether!

Then you can get these materials(e.g. blaze rods) on your original over-world world and do whatever you wish!

---

**For clarification**, only your nether seed gets reset when you reset the nether. Your over- world world is completely untouched.

[Source 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123481/what-happens-when-i-reset-the-nether?rq=1)

[Source 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74664/how-big-is-the-nether-in-minecraft-xbox-360-edition?rq=1)

Comment: So the entire seed gets reset (overworld included) or just the nether seed?

Comment: @Ben Just the nether seed. That's why I mentioned you could take your new items from the nether into your original map in the overworld.